# Create a 3D numpy array with 3 2D numpy arrays or 3 1D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have three numpy 2D arrays:

```
A1 with the shape of (x * y)
A2 with the shape of (x * z)
A3 with the shape of (y * z)
```

The values in the three arrays are either True or False. Now, I want to create a 3D array of shape (x * y * z) so that each element in the 3D array follows:

```
3D_array[x, y, z] = A1[x, y] & A2[x, z] & A3[y, z]
```

I know I can do with a loop. But is there any faster way to do this? Like through vectorization?

Alternatively, the three 2D arrays are actually just some pair-wise interaction between three 1D arrays. So a more general way to present my question is:

Give three 1D numpy array (X), (Y), (Z) in length of x, y, z respectively, what is the best way to create a 3D numpy array so that each element in the 3D array equals:

```
3D_array[i, j, k] = my_function(X[i], Y[j], Z[k])
```

where the my_function is a customized function that returns, say, True/False. Again, I am looking for something better than looping.

Any solutions to either the first question or the more general one are welcomed. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

```py
np.apply_along_axis(sum, axis=0, np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y, z)))
```

**Walkthrough:**

Let's have a look at a concrete example and start by creating three 1-d arrays:

```py
x, y, z = [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]
```

Now, let's turn these into a [meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```py
a, b, c = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
```

This time we get three 3-d arrays:

```py
>>> a
array([[[1, 1],
        [2, 2]],

       [[1, 1],
        [2, 2]]])
```

This array corresponds to our first argument, which is `1` half of the time and `2` the other half. These are the two values we have in `x`. We have eight values in total because the shape of our eventual output is supposed to be `2 x 2 x 2 = 8`.

Similarly, we have `b` and `c`:

```py
>>> b
array([[[3, 3],
        [3, 3]],

       [[4, 4],
        [4, 4]]])
>>> c
array([[[5, 6],
        [5, 6]],

       [[5, 6],
        [5, 6]]])
```

At this point you can already start combining these three arrays in various ways so for simple functions (those you can split into two steps) you can simply run `a + b + c` or `a & b & c`.

In the general case you might want to define functions that take three numbers and produce a single output based on arbitrary logic. To apply such functions, we first need to [stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) these three arrays into a single one by doing:

```py
>>> np.stack([a, b, c])
array([[[[1, 1],
         [2, 2]],

        [[1, 1],
         [2, 2]]],


       [[[3, 3],
         [3, 3]],

        [[4, 4],
         [4, 4]]],


       [[[5, 6],
         [5, 6]],

        [[5, 6],
         [5, 6]]]])
```

Now we have three arrays of size eight (the actual shape is `3,2,2,2`) and we want to [apply](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) a function eight times to three numbers at a time:

```py
>>> np.apply_along_axis(sum, axis=0, np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y, z)))
array([[[ 9, 10],
        [10, 11]],

       [[10, 11],
        [11, 12]]])
```

We get eight points as a result as expected where each point is the sum of one of `1` or `2`, one of `3` or `4` and one of `5` or `6`.

Beware that `numpy` will pass 1-d arrays to `f` rather than a sequence of arguments so if you have a function like:

```py
def f(a, b, c):
  return a + b - c
```

you will need to define an additional function that wraps the original one:

```py
def f2(vals):
  return f(*vals)

# Alternatively:
f2 = lambda x: f(*x)
```

So, now we can apply `f2` to our data:

```py
>>> np.apply_along_axis(f2, 0, np.stack(np.meshgrid(x, y, z)))
array([[[-1, -2],
        [ 0, -1]],

       [[ 0, -1],
        [ 1,  0]]])
```

Comment: This is what I have been looking for! Thank you!

Comment: That `apply_along` with `sum` is a slow way of doing `np.stack(np.meshgrid(x,y,z)).sum(axis=0)`.  (or even `np.sum((a,b,c),axis=0)`.  Of course not every function has an axis parameter like that.  But in my experience `apply_along_axis` is not a performance tool.

Comment: Agree 100%, I think the OP wanted a “neat solution”

Answer (score 0):

With broadcasting

```
3D_array[x, y, z] = A1[x, y] & A2[x, z] & A3[y, z]
```

could be done with:

```
B = A1[:,:,None] & A2[:,None,:] & A3[None,:,:]
```

Effectively this turns all 3 arrays into 3d arrays that work together with most of the `numpy` operators.

The more general case:

```
3D_array[i, j, k] = my_function(X[i], Y[j], Z[k])
```

is harder.

```
B = X[:,None,None] + Y[None,:,None] + Z[None,None,:]
```

Again this works for operators (and `ufunc`) that use broadcasting, but not for an user defined function that only works with scalars.

I hesitate to suggest this, but maybe it necessary.  `np.vectorize` can create a function that works with broadcasting like this.  But it is not a performance tool.

The `apply_along_axis` suggested in the othe answer isn't a performance tool it.  It iterates on the `other` axes.  For multidimensional arrays like this it can the code simpler than more explicit iteration, but not faster.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but also huge thanks. Your solution "B = A1[:,:,None] & A2[:,None,:] & A3[None,:,:]" helped me to reduce my code run time from 1hour to 4 min.